# What does Container.validate() method do?

Tags: java, swing, awt

There seems to be many methods in Java awt [Container](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) class that are related to *validate*. Apparently they don't do data validation. Is it useful for a Swing developer in any cases? Some of the methods:
validate(), invalidate(), validateTree(), isValid() etc.

Answer (score 8):

Citing the [API doc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29):

> The validate method is used to cause a
>   container to lay out its subcomponents
>   again. It should be invoked when this
>   container's subcomponents are modified
>   (added to or removed from the
>   container, or layout-related
>   information changed) after the
>   container has been displayed.

Comment: You read the RTRM! (Although typically you would use `JComponent.revalidate`.)

Answer (score 3):

Validation in a Swing context concerns requesting a component to lay-out its sub-components after one of these is modified.

For example, suppose you implement a custom JDialog with a button "Show Filters".  Upon clicking this button, you might want to add an additional "filter" panel to the south of the JDialog.  Upon adding the new sub-panel you would be required to call validate() on the JDialog to cause it to lay-out the new panel correctly.

Comment: +1. Some people also call validate() as a talisman to magically make things work right...so watch for unnecessary calls if you're working in other people's GUI code.